# Objective C Project using C++ POSIX Classes

Tags: c++, iphone, objective-c, cocoa, ios

I have to create a iOS Programm using Code of some C++ POSIX Classes.
I already read the "Using C++ With Objective-C" manual of the Apple Developer Center.
They describe how to mix C++ & Objective C code in a .mm file.

My question is, is there any possibility to use the C++ Classes in my .h/.m files of a normal Objective C Project?

Or is it necessary to write the whole Project in that .mm file style with its own main?

Answer (score 2):

You can combine in a project any types of files, say `.c`, `.m`, `.cpp` and `.mm`, and the compiler is chosen automatically depending on the extension. For example, you can keep the standard `main.m` file which comes with the XCode template, and add your new `.h` and `.mm` files to use Objective-C++.

In other words, there's no distinction between a *normal Objective-C* project and a *Objective-C++* project. You just have to use `.mm` extension for the specific files which needs Objective-C++. This can be used in any project.

Comment: Okay for example I have a normal iPhone Project and I want to use an in C++ written Class in a view controller. It is not possible just to include the .h file of the C++ Code for using the C++ classes. Is there anything I forgot?

Comment: You can. You just need to change the extension of your view controller implementation file from `.m` to `.mm`. You can change the file name inside XCode.

Answer (score 0):

You have to force compilation of the Obj-C files in which you want to use C++ to Obj-C++ in the build menu. You can then create and use C++ objects in your Obj-C classes.

Comment: Why not just name the implementation files with the .mm extension? Then you don't need to force anything in the project.

Comment: Depends on if you want to reuse these files for a project other than an iOS one.

Comment: Where can you use an Objective-C (.m) file where you can't use an Objective-C++ (.mm) file?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to use the C++. In my projects I usually only make a few calls out to do some heavy lifting, etc.

What I do is have C++ in .cpp files, then create a few .mm files that have headers that have no C++ in them.  These .mm files are obj-c wrappers for the C++. Then the C++ is 'contained' to the original posix files, plus a few files that give the C++ classes and calls all the interface you need. As few .mm files as possible is a good thing.

Keeping the C++ out of most of your code makes debugging, etc easier.

--Tom

Answer (score 0):

Select Project directory in Xcode, In Build Settings tap, choose **"Compile Sources As" is  Objective-C++**. No need change name type from .m to .mm.