# iOS,CoreAudio: a strange 'CADebugPrintf.h: no such file or directory ... ' error

Tags: ios, core-audio

There are bunch of helper filess in 'iPublicUtility' folder of several audio related Apple sample codes, such as aurioTouch:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch/Introduction/Intro.html

I can build these samples fine.  But whenever I create a new project for testing and include the files from 'iPublicUtility' folder, I get:
'CADebugPrintf.h: no such file or directory ... ' error in 'CADebugMacros.h' file.

I made the settings of my test project to coincide with Apple samples, but this error is
not going away.  Any suggestion?

SDK: iOS 4.2, 
iMac OSX 10.6.6

Thanks all.

sy

Answer (score 34):

select the Target, open the Build Settings pane, search for "Preprocessor Macros". Leave the fields blank (I've got rid of a DEBUG entry)

Comment: Seems like a bad solution with potentially widespread debug effects - adding the missing file would be proper: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/CoreAudioUtilityClasses/Listings/CoreAudio_PublicUtility_CADebugPrintf_h.html

Answer (score 22):

I used the answer provided by Justin and it worked fine, until I installed Xcode 4.3.1 and the problem came back.

Currently I solved this by downloading CADebugPrintf.h and .cpp.

I found the 2 files at this link:

http://svn.perian.org/trunk/CoreAudio/PublicUtility/

Cheers.

Comment: After you added the files into your project, be sure to goto Targets > Build Phases > Compile Sources, and ensure that the 2 files are in the list. If not, add it, then build.

Comment: That version (1.0.1) is outdated - I'd go here for v1.1: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/CoreAudioUtilityClasses/Listings/CoreAudio_PublicUtility_CADebugPrintf_h.html

Answer (score 9):

i have three distributions of Xcode installed.

the file exists in all three.

1) verify that the file exists on your system.

2a) add a search path to your project for the PublicUtility directory

or

2b) add the header to the target's "copy headers" build phase

depending on how many depends you have for these files, you may want a more reliable approach (which exists). one (fairly) safe/easy way to do this if you use a lot of the audio technologies and sources is to add its parent dir's parent dir to your search paths or source trees (recursively).

another way is to add it to a shared build settings file.

you could also copy a specific release someplace, then add that to your search paths. just be aware that the sources get updated somewhat regularly, so you'll have to update it when it's a good time for you. in this case, you'll should change your project references as well.

**Edit: Adding the search path (2a)**

One way to add a search path (assuming Xcode tools are installed at : /Developer/):

1) In Xcode (3), select the target.

2) cmd+i (get info)

3) select the "Build" tab of the info window

4) enter HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS into the search field

5) if the value is not defined at this level (e.g., it is not bold), then set the value to **/Developer/Extras/CoreAudio/PublicUtility/ $(inherited)**

if it is already defined at that level, then add **/Developer/Extras/CoreAudio/PublicUtility/** to the list of directories to search (the value).

if you want to search the library recursively, use **/Developer/Extras/CoreAudio/****. this may be useful when building AUs, or other projects which require the AU includes and PublicUtility includes.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem, but seemed to have fixed it by downloading from the link below and adding in the missing CADebugPrintf.h and CADebugPrintf.cpp files.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CoreAudioUtilityClasses/Listings/CoreAudio_PublicUtility_CADebugPrintf_h.html

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and downloading the files into the iPublicUtility folder did not solve it. I found the answer by accident while learning about .mm extension files on this page:

[Objective C Project using C++ POSIX Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651974/objective-c-project-using-c-posix-classes)

I renamed my implementation file with a .mm and the compiler errors disappeared. Hope this may help someone down the line!